# Foreign key in C#

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, database

I have two tables, A and B, in a dataset in SQL Server; I have created a connection to the dataset in a c# project in visual studio. How can I create a foreign key ( A is the parent) between my two tables ? I want to create the foreign key in visual studio and that it is visible in SQL server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want create relationship in two table
Refer this link

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/Blogs/5608/create-a-relationship-between-two-dataset-tables.aspx

Code from the linked article:

```
  DataSet objDS = new DataSet();
  objDS.Tables.Add(Employee);
  objDS.Tables.Add(Department);
  DataRelation objRelation = new DataRelation("objRelation",
  Employee.Columns["EmpID"], Department.Columns["EmpID"]);
  objDS.Relations.Add(objRelation);
```

Comment: Ok but in this way is the foreign key visible in sql server ?

Comment: It is not visible in sql server. It should be create only to application code. It is use only for code.

Comment: How can I do to make the foreign key visible in sql server ? I want to create in visual studio a key visible in sql server, is it possible ?